# Model Value is null in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a post method, where i am trying to post the value of textbox to database, for this i am doing all the necessary steps, but in that post method my model is null. Find the code below,
My Simple Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(QuestionBankModel question)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My Model

```
public class QuestionBankModel
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
    }
```

My View

```
@model OnlinePariksha.Models.QuestionBankModel
@{
    var CustomerInfo = (OnlinePariksha.Models.UserLoginModel)Session["UserInfo"];
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Admin.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AdminDashboard", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div id="questionsDiv" style="width:100%; display:none;">
    <div style="width:200px">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td><span><b>Question:</b></span></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox(Model.question, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } })
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="sucessBtn1" value="Save" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Did i miss anything?

Comment: So the QuestionBankModel has 1 property: question. And upon hitting the Index action on HttpPost, that question's value is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the POST method parameter name is the same name as your model property (and as a result model binding fails). Change the method signature to

```
public ActionResult Index(QuestionBankModel model)
{
  ...
}
```

or any other parameter name that is not the same as a model property.

By way of explanation, the `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes a new instance of `QuestionBankModel`. It then inspects the form (and other) values and sees `question="SomeStringYouEntered"`. It then searches for a property named `question` (in order to set its value). The first one it finds is your method parameter so it internally it does `QuestionBankModel question = "SomeStringYouEntered";` which fails (you cant assign a strung to a complex object) and the model parameter now becomes `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using @HTML.TextBoxFor?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.question,new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } })
```

Comment: How about try typing something into the textbox, then click "Submit"?

Answer (score 0):

Html.TextBox is being used incorrectly because the first parameter is the name of the textbox and you're passing the value of question.  I would use this instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.question)
```